# Regarding emailing to prospective Professors after submitting application

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, email

I have applied to a US university for Fall 2023. I have mentioned 4 Professors name in the SoP though I haven’t contact them before submitting application. Now I want to email them to inform them that I am interested to working with them. If they read my application, Will they mind if they see that I have mentioned other Professors name also? Will that have a negative impact on the outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you get accepted there is little point in it and the most likely outcome will be either "ignored" or "Lets talk if you get accepted."

In most fields, individual professors aren't likely to be on the admissions committee, though a few will. They are unlikely to interfere in the process either positively or negatively. So, with a few exceptions, your mail is just a distraction; a bit of noise.

You might be better to wait until you actually start in the program, ask around about how the professors treat students and have a sit-down with the most likely people, asking about possible topics.

If you have only a bachelors at the time you start, there is no real need to have that conversation in the first year or two while you are preparing for comprehensive exams (most places, most fields).

No, it probably won't have a negative effect, but not positive either.

See: [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in Country X?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/75368)

Comment: Thanks for this insightful answer. However, I am from Agricultural Sciences background where it’s more likely to be funded by the Professors rather than the department. That’s why, I am concerned as I didn’t communicate with them before submitting the application.